# How to model AJAX interaction with java spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to model a simple ajax interaction between my javascript code and my server.

### Client

```
data = {};
data.url = "google.com";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/first/second",
    data: data,
    cache: false
}).done(function(response) {
    Console.log("hello");
});
```

### Server

```
@Controller
@HttpOptions(sslHandling = SslHandlingOption.NON_SSL_REDIRECTS_TO_SSL)
public class myController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/first/second", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> returnURL(@RequestParam(value = "url") String URL) {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap.put("url", URL);
        return responseMap;
    }
}
```

### My Error

In the logs, I am getting a `500 (Internal Server error)`.

### Constraints

This code is obviously dumbed down to not give away company info, but the following constraints must be adheared to:

- Request method must be POST
- the data must be passed to the server as shown (initialized as a blank object)

Comment: Please include full stacktrace of error and specify on what line is it occurring it on.

Comment: where is the domain name in the ajax call you are making. it must have something like "http://localhost:8080" or some domain name.

Comment: In your ajax call url must be url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/first/second or localhost:8080/applicationname/first/second.